# Do Biblical Unitarians worship Jesus or venerate him?

Tags: worship, biblical-unitarian

In [this Biblical Unitarian answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/93948/47250) to a question asking after differences in the way that Catholics view Mary vs. how Biblical Unitarians view Jesus there appears the following:

> Like Mary in Catholicism with special 'veneration' or devotion, there is an attitude towards Jesus which others might consider 'worship' and inappropriate towards anyone except God, and which is not equal to other humans in heaven.

Catholics insist that the veneration they direct towards Mary is not the same as the worship that belongs to God alone.  Of course, for Catholics, God indicates the three persons of the Trinity.

Given the block-quote above my question is: Do Biblical Unitarians worship Jesus or only venerate him in the same sense in which Catholics venerate Mary?

Comment: Good question.   I suspect it is all about the various ways proskuneo is used in scripture.  Bowing before a higher ranking human is worship technically

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/68592/what-does-%cf%80%cf%81%ce%bf%cf%83%ce%ba%cf%85%ce%bd%ce%ad%cf%89-translated-worship-mean-in-matt-22

Comment: Catholics distinguish between (a) Latria, or the highest religious worship which is due to God alone and (b) Doulia - inferior religious worship due in various degrees to saints and angels according to their rank. Unitarians never use that idea because they say Jesus was a great man and a prophet of God, but not God himself.

Comment: @anne wouldn’t Unitarians be cool with Doulia directed towards Jesus?

Comment: @User 14  No, I don't think so (though I stand to be corrected) because they rightly maintain that no created creature is to be given any kind of worship, adoration or reverence. They say Jesus was created; that he had a starting point in time. Catholics do not, but when it comes to their adoration of Mary, they might be skating on thin ice (theologically speaking!) as they know Mary was created, having a starting point in time. But I don't want to get into a debate about that so will say no more.

Comment: Just for clarity here is a Catholic definition of ***Dulia***: "A theological term signifying the honour paid to the saints, while ***latria*** means worship given to God alone, and ***hyperdulia*** the veneration offered to the Blessed Virgin Mary."

Comment: 'He that abideth in the doctrine of Christ hath both the Father and the Son'. But if one does not abide in the doctrine of Christ 'he knoweth not God'. If certain doctrine is not _lived in_ then there is no knowledge of whom God actually is. (And therefore there is no worship of God at all, just worship of the creature. ) This question is about the _defining_ of 'the doctrine of Christ'. Up-voted +1.

Comment: No, Biblical Unitarians do not worship Jesus Christ. They will admit that Jesus Christ is God's son but He is not divine. Hebrews 1:6 where His Father states "And let all the angels of God worship Him." The word worship in Greek is "proskuneo," and is actual worship. At Luke 4:8, "It is written, you shall worship the Lord your God and serve Him only." So, at Hebrews 1:6, Who would God require the angels to worship, a man, creature, a fellow angel? To ask these questions is to answer them. God requires them to worship none but God, this passage proves that the Son of God should be worshipped .

Answer (score 2):

**Do Biblical Unitarians worship Jesus or venerate him?**

The short answer is **no**, they do not worship Jesus in the sense as adoring him as God, but merely venerate him as the Son of God in his earthly humanity. Jesus is not Divine according to Biblical Unitarians.

Biblical Unitarians may not worship Jesus, but may venerate him as the Son of God.

There are many articles on the Internet by Biblical Unitarian which get into the definition of worship as respect or honouring Jesus in his humanity. But they carefully avoid placing the meaning of worship to mean the adoration that is reserved to God alone.

The article [*Can we “worship” Jesus Christ?*](https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/videos/can-we-worship-jesus-christ) is a prime example as to what I am getting at. Nowhere in the long post does it even comes close to admitting that Jesus may be adored as God, but more closely he may be respected and honoured or perhaps even venerated because he is the Son of God, but not God.

The *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy Archive* has the following to say about Biblical Unitarians in it’s main article on [Unitarianism](https://plato.stanford.edu/Archives/spr2023/entries/trinity/unitarianism.html)

> There are presently a number of small Christian groups calling themselves “biblical unitarians” (or: Christian monotheists or one God believers)to distinguish themselves from late 19th to 21st century Unitarians and Unitarian Universalists. Their arguments draw on early modern unitarian sources, while eschewing some of the idiosyncrasies of Socinus’s theology and most of the extra revisions of the Priestley-derived stream of unitarians. Like late 18th to early 19th century unitarians, they argue at length that trinitarianism has no biblical foundation, and is inconsistent with its clear teachings. They also reject trinitarianism as contradictory or unintelligible, as involving idolatry, and as having been, as it were, illegally imported from Platonic philosophy (Buzzard 2007; Buzzard and Hunting 1999; Graeser et al. 2000; Snedeker 1998). On some issues they draw support from recent biblical scholarship, for example, the point that talk of “generation” and “procession” in the gospel of John doesn’t support later claims about inter-trinitarian relations (Buzzard and Hunting 1999, 306–8). Although this literature points out real tensions within contemporary theology (between text-oriented commentators and systematic theologians) it is widely ignored in academic theology and philosophy, and its adherents are generally excluded from the institutions of mainstream Christianity.

Answer (score 0):

As a non-Trinitarian, the Biblical answer to this question is easy.  It is found in the first chapter of Hebrews.

> <sup>1</sup>God, who at sundry times and in divers manners spake in
> time past unto the fathers by the prophets, 
> <sup>2</sup>Hath in
> these last days spoken unto us by **his Son**, whom he hath appointed heir
> of all things, by whom also he made the worlds; 
> <sup>3</sup>Who
> being the brightness of his glory, and the express image of his
> person, and upholding all things by the word of his power, when he had
> by himself purged our sins, sat down on the right hand of the Majesty
> on high: 
> <sup>4</sup>Being made so much better than the angels, as
> he hath by inheritance obtained a more excellent name than they.
>
> <sup>5</sup>For unto which of the angels said he at any time, Thou
> art **my Son**, this day have I begotten thee? And again, I will be to him
> a Father, and he shall be to me **a Son**? 
> <sup>6</sup>And again, when
> he bringeth in **the firstbegotten** into the world, he saith, **And let all
> the angels of God worship him.** (Hebrews 1:1-6, KJV)

Depending on how one chooses to interpret this passage, God is either commanding, or permitting, the worship of His Son.

If the Son were already God, it would be no sin to worship him, and there would be no need for this command.  But given that God has expressly enjoined upon His subjects the worship of His Son, it is no sin to do so, whether the Son is a created being or not.  If the angels of Heaven, who are perfect, worship the Son, so may we who are created even lower than the angels.

**Conclusion**

Jesus may be freely worshiped by all.

Comment: Here is an interesting article on the etymology of *proskuneo*.  https://www.abarim-publications.com/DictionaryG/p/p-r-o-s-k-u-n-e-om.html  If this word (which is in the imperative mood), indeed, means 'to advance toward to kiss and ultimately fully merge with' rather than some kind of religious activity then Psalm 2 takes on a whole new aspect.

Comment: @MikeBorden I would agree that "proskuneo" could mean "bow" or "prostrate oneself" etc. and not necessarily "worship."  However, there is no escaping the Ten Commandments which spell out the definition of worship as including such actions.  "Thou shalt not bow down thyself to them, nor serve them..." (Exodus 20:5, KJV).  In fact, the Ten Commandments also do not use the word "worship," and yet no serious Bible student would contest the fact that it goes against the Commandments to worship anyone or anything other than the true God.

Comment: " no serious Bible student would contest the fact that it goes against the Commandments to worship anyone or anything other than the true God."  And Jesus is to be worshiped so He cannot be other than the true God.

Comment: @MikeBorden Well, as the Bible indicates, we are given permission to worship Jesus.  We are commanded to worship God.  Somehow, there seems to be some difference there...and Jesus said that the Father was the only true God.

Comment: "true" may not be the very best translation:  The adjective αληθινος (alethinos), meaning pertaining to or in pursuit of convention and synchronization: something about which there is no disagreement or about which there will be no disagreement when all that can be unearthed is unearthed. Something that will never fail, never go away and has always been part of the eternal order of creation.

Comment: This word is often translated with true or genuine, but it should be noted that this word describes something that is part of the physical universe, not something that exist in some moral code, cultural expression or even the best intentions or sincerest beliefs of humans.

Comment: The word underneath "true" may have more to do with Fatherhood in the sense of source that it does as opposite of false.  The eternally begotten Son still has Father as source even though there is no beginning per se.

Comment: @MikeBorden Are you comfortable with rationalizing away the plain truths of the Bible in this manner?  The logic of saying "true" may not mean "true" is definitely becoming ubiquitous in modern society, but I don't find it becoming of a Bible student.  The inconvenient truth here is that we should be willing to accept a "thus saith the Lord" over and above our own cherished and prideful opinion.  Any day.

Comment: It is not as though I am setting up 'true' to mean false.  Those who have received his testimony have set their seals to this; that God is true.  'Genuine' is better than 'true' as opposed to false.  Here is what Thayer has to say:  "that which has not only the name and resemblance, but the real nature corresponding to the name, in every respect corresponding to the idea signified by the name, real, true genuine"

Comment: Such that 1 John 5:20 makes clear the God who is true:  And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an understanding, that we may know him that is true, and **we are in him that is true, even in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God, and eternal life**.   Father over/Son in submission/united in one Spirit.  This is the true *Theos*.

Comment: @MikeBorden If the true God is known by His son, then it is clearly the Father of said son who is God.  To then make the Son be God, too, would be like pulling oneself up by one's own bootstraps--and make no logical sense.  If God is known by His son, does the "God the Son" _also_ have a son by which he could then be known?  Do we then worship God's _grandson_, too? Trinitarian logic is pure confusion, which is why God says "the wisdom of man is foolishness with God."  I think John has been quite clear--helping us know plainly that God is the Father of the Son.

Comment: Of course God (*theos*) is the Father of the Son.  But the Son is also of the Father.  Is it not a clear principle that like begets like?  What exactly would *theos* beget if not *theos*.  The Son of God came so that we may know him that is true (Father) and we are in him that is true (Son).  This is the true God.

Comment: @MikeBorden Can you beget yourself?

Comment: I have begotten two human beings.  Neither of them are Fathers.

Comment: @MikeBorden And neither of them are you.  "God" is not a surname.  He is a Being.

Comment: Yes.  God is **Theos** (Divine Being).  He has revealed Himself as Father over/Son in submission/ united in one Spirit.  We can be done if you would like or go into chat.  Up to you.  I know whom I have believed; who has, is, and will save me.